# ARCore – Session, Frame, Camera and Pose

Tags: java, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm studying the ARCore [References](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/), [Develop](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/), make the course from [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ar), and read, understood and learn from the [Samples](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart).

But I still missing some definition with some real use examples.

What is a session? Every time that I need a ARCore use I need a session? Session always has a camera connect so I can see and draw/renderer my 3D models in the screen? Can I do this without a Session?

Camera has a getPose and Frame has a GetPose, what are the diferences between they?

I thought about make this questions split but somehow I know that they are all connected. Sessions, CameraAr, Frame and Pose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### About ArSession

> ***`ArSession` is the most crucial element in AR puzzle***. Session manages AR system state and handles the session lifecycle. **Session class** is the main entry point to the ARCore API. This class allows the user to create a session, configure it, start or stop it and, most importantly, receive `ArFrames` that allow access to `ARCamera` image and device **Pose**.

> **In order to use ARCore you need an `ArSession`. ARCore doesn't render 3D models (`Renderables`). This job is for `Sceneform` framework**.

[image]

Code's example:

```
private Session mSession;
Config config = new Config(mSession);

if (!mSession.isSupported(config)) {
    showSnackbarMessage("This phone doesn't support AR", true);
}
mSession.configure(config);
```

Also Session's configuration can include nested classes:

- **Config.AugmentedFaceMode** (Selects the behaviour of `Augmented Faces` subsystem)
- **Config.CloudAnchorMode** (The cloud anchor mode in `Config`)
- **Config.FocusMode** (Selects the desired behaviour of the `camera focus` subsystem)
- **Config.LightEstimationMode** (Select the behaviour of the `lighting estimation` subsystem)
- **Config.PlaneFindingMode** (Select the behaviour of the `plane detection` subsystem)
- **Config.UpdateMode** (Selects the behaviour of `update()`)

### About Pose

> **`Pose`** represents an immutable rigid transformation from one coordinate space to another. As provided from all ARCore APIs, Poses always describe the transformation from object's local coordinate space to the world coordinate space. The transformation is defined using a quaternion rotation about the origin followed by a translation.

Code's example:

```
float[] position = { 0, 0, -2.2 };      //  { x, y, z } position 
float[] rotation = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };      //  { x, y, z, w } quaternion rotation

Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
Anchor myAnchor = session.createAnchor(new Pose(position, rotation));
```

### About ArCamera

> **`ArCamera`** represents a virtual camera, which determines the perspective through which the scene is viewed. If the camera is part of an `ArSceneView`, then the camera automatically tracks the **Camera Pose** from ARCore. ArCamera is a long-lived object and the properties of camera are updated every time `Session.update()` is called. `Camera` class provides information about the camera that is used to capture images and additional info inside each `ArFrame`.

Code's example:

```
// Shared camera access with ARCore

sharedSession = new Session(this, EnumSet.of(Session.Feature.SHARED_CAMERA))
sharedCamera = sharedSession.getSharedCamera();
cameraId = sharedSession.getCameraConfig().getCameraId();
```

### About ArFrame

> When ARCore's understanding of the environment changes, it adjusts its model of the **world** to keep things consistent. When this happens, the numerical location (coordinates) of the `ARCamera` and `ARAnchors` can change significantly to maintain appropriate relative positions of the physical locations they represent.These changes mean that every `ArFrame` should be considered to be in a completely unique **world coordinate space**. The numerical coordinates of `ARAnchors` and the `ARCamera` should never be used outside the rendering frame during which they were retrieved.

> Every **`ArFrame`** stores the following info about ARCore's state::

- RGB image itself
- Tracking status
- The pose of the camera relative to the world
- Estimated lighting parameters
- Information on updates to objects (like Point Clouds)

Code's example:

```
private void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) {

    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

    // .............
}
```

Additionally, you can read [this useful post](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/com.google.ar.core.Camera).