# Is it possible to run ARCamera in the background without previewing it on Android?

Tags: android, camera, arcore

I am fairly new to Android and especially to the various camera systems in this platform. I'm building an app where I need to integrate ARCore only to track the camera pose (among other things like objects in the scene, planes etc). I don't want to augment anything in the "real world" , so I am not looking to preview the frames being fed to the camera. I've looked through all of the examples in the arcore-sdk and sample code in google's documentation. None of them cover my use case where I want to be able to fetch camera's pose *without* previewing the camera images onto a surface view or something. I also don't want to 'fake' it by creating a view and hiding it. I would like to know if anyone has experience with such a thing or any ideas how we can achieve it or if we can achieve this at all? Does ARCore even support this?

UPDATE: I found this https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/259 where they mention that it's possible with just an OpenGL context. But I have no clue how to get started. Any samples or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can run an [ArSession](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/ar-session) for tracking. ArSession doesn't depend on View.

Comment: Appreciate the response! Can you give me more info if you happen to know? Any examples or tutorials on how to get a reference to the ArCamera from the frames and thereby query the pose and other information? I am still struggling to get a reference to the frames so that I can get a handle of the ArCamera associated with them.

Comment: You are right, there is very little info on this topic. Here are [First link](https://developers.google.cn/ar/develop/java/camera-sharing?hl=en) and [Second link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/graphics-Guides/dev-guide-java-0000001059882631).

Comment: And read these posts, please – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763412/arcore-session-frame-camera-and-pose and https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/com.google.ar.core.Camera